# How to print an XSL property?

Tags: xml, fonts, xsl-fo, docbook

I'm having a font problem in a DocBook project. For a particular character (the CIRCLE LATIN A), one FO processor prints a blank space (' '), and a second prints a number sign ('#'). During troubleshooting, I was asked what font I am using.

I know the fonts are specified in `body.font.family` and `title.font.family`. How do I print the value of the property? What command is used to print a DocBook property?

Or maybe I should backup: can DocBook properties be dumped with a command like Linux kernel values using `sysctrl`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All customizable properties in DocBook-XSL (parameters, attribute-sets, processing instructions) are already "dumped" in the documentation: http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/.

The font properties for XSL-FO that you mention are XSLT parameters:

- http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/fo/body.font.family.html
- http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/fo/title.font.family.html

If you haven't customized these parameters, they have the default values shown in the documentation.

See also these sections from "DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide":

- http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Typography.html#BodyAndTitleFonts
- http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/AddFont.html.